# Pourquoi la diphtongue latine "al" est devenue "au" en Français ?

Tags: étymologie

Plusieurs mots écrits avec la diphtongue "au" s'écrivaient auparavant avec un "al" en ancien français/latin.

Exemples:

- S**al**mo -> S**au**mon
- **Al**cun -> **Au**cun
- F**al**sus -> F**au**x

Pourqoi se changement de lettre s'est produit au fil du temps ?